# Understanding CATransform3D

Tags: uiview, catransform3d, quartz-core

I'm playing with CATransform3DMakeRotation in a UIView, and I'm trying to do a 45º, transform like it's laying backwards:

[image: http://cl.ly/2A2p1W1e2N3a1W181r35]

This is the "code" I have, but clearly doesn't do it.

```
CATransform3D _tr = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.14/4, 1, 0, 0);
view.layer.transform = _tr;
```

please help me understand the params.
Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI, but `M_PI` can be used instead of the 3.14 constant. And `M_PI_4` instead of 3.14/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, your code is correct, but to get the perspective effect, you need to set the `sublayerTransform` of the superview's layer to something like this:

```
CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -850;
myView.layer.sublayerTransform = perspectiveTransform;
```

You can experiment with different values for different amounts of distortion.

Comment: can you explain please what you're doing there?. I want to learn, not just copy-paste and tweak values.

Comment: For posterity, Apple explains what .m34 and 850 would mean here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW13